# how to split a matrix of size 88x88 in 4 parts in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, split, size

so far i have done
Declare a random Matrix M of size 88 x 88
Type of M should be uint8 (all values should be between 0 to 255).
Spilt the Matrix into 4 parts: p1, p2, p3, p4 
Transpose all parts
Concatenate all these four parts into new matrix N

Comment: SO is not a homework service ...

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: Consider sharing with us what you have tried.

Comment: Please add that code into the question instead of posting as comments. Use `edit` button right below the question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not much clear in the question, Maybe this helps,

```
M = uint8(randi([0 255],[88 88]));
p1 = M(1:end/2    ,1:end/2    );
p2 = M(1:end/2    ,end/2+1:end);
p3 = M(end/2+1:end,1:end/2    );
p4 = M(end/2+1:end,end/2+1:end);
N = [p1' p2';p3' p4'];
```

Comment: Hint: Use `end` to make this approach work for matrices of different sizes. E.g. p2 = `M(1:end, (end/2+1):end);`

Answer (score 1):

### Approach #1

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use **[`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/blockproc.htm)** for a pretty straight-forward solution to this -

```
fun = @(block_struct) transpose(block_struct.data);
N = blockproc(M, [size(M,1)/2 size(M,2)/2], fun)
```

---

### Approach #2

Let's suppose you have an input matrix of size `m x n` and you would like to partition it into `dim1p` parts along the rows and `dim2p` parts along the columns, so that each block is of size `m/dim1p x n/dim2p` and you would like transpose them and finally concatenate them back to form a 2D array. This could be thought of as a **`general case`** of what you had proposed in the question.

To solve such a case with performance in mind, you can use this -

```
[m,n] = size(M); %// Get size

dim1p = 2; %// number of parts to be partitioned along dimension-1 (rows)
dim2p = 2; %// number of parts to be partitioned along dimension-2 (columns)

%// Split and transpose, resulting in a 3D array
A = reshape(permute(reshape(M, m, n/dim2p, []), [2 1 3]), n/dim2p, m/dim1p, []);

%// Join the 3D slices back into a 2D array for the desired output
nrows = n*dim1p/dim2p;
N = reshape(permute(reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),nrows,dim2p,[]),[1 3 2]),nrows,[])
```

Sample run (assuming M as `9 x 8` sized and partitioning it into `3` and `4` parts along the rows and columns respectively so that each block is of size `3 x 2`) -

```
M =
     5     6     2     6     4     2     1     3
     2     8     8     1     3     8     3     7
     5     1     6     8     4     1     6     8
     6     5     7     3     3     6     7     1
     4     3     9     3     2     2     5     3
     4     9     5     7     6     2     2     1
     7     6     2     5     9     3     5     6
     8     9     5     6     9     6     7     1
     1     1     3     3     4     9     1     3
dim1p =
     3
dim2p =
     4
N =
     5     2     5     2     8     6     4     3     4     1     3     6
     6     8     1     6     1     8     2     8     1     3     7     8
     6     4     4     7     9     5     3     2     6     7     5     2
     5     3     9     3     3     7     6     2     2     1     3     1
     7     8     1     2     5     3     9     9     4     5     7     1
     6     9     1     5     6     3     3     6     9     6     1     3
```

Comment: Homework #2 in MATLAB 101: Student uses 4 `reshape` and 3 `permute` to solve a trivial problem as efficient as possible. Or, uses an anonymous function handle inside `blockproc` in order to make it "straight forward". I guess the TA will be impressed! +1 for providing a very nice answer to a not-so-good question in a way that future visitors can benefit from, but OP probably won't dare to use (imagine trying to answer "How does the code work" two weeks after you're introduced to MATLAB / programming in general) =P

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks for the +1! Well, I mostly keep in mind is having useful future resources for future readers and myself too. Yeah, beginners might take some time to take it all in, but I guess to really solve a problem one has to see how to expand it to a bigger scale which this solution tries to achieve. Hopefully, OP would draw some inspiration from it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to split up the matrix into a 2 x 2 grid of cells, transpose each of the cell's contents using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), then piece them all together using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).  Therefore:

```
[rows, cols] = size(M);
C = mat2cell(M, [rows/2, rows/2], [cols/2, cols/2]);
D = cellfun(@transpose, C, 'uni', 0);
out = cell2mat(D);
```

Minor note:  This only works when the rows and columns are both even.